# SharePoint 2010 Content deployment - List Item - Attachment - Property missing?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

The scenario is

- Farm A - internal farm - [Content deployment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721058%28v=office.14%29.aspx) job running fine.
- Farm B - external farm

To clear some things, all the content deployment jobs are running fine. There is nothing wrong.

**The problem:**

We have some custom lists with items added programmatically, these items have attachments and these attachments have properties.

The problem is that these properties are not included on content deployment job!

Adding the properties to the attachment file

```
SPFile targetFile = Web.GetFile(fileURL);
targetFile.Properties.Add("MyCustomProp", "Sadly i don't get copied by Ccontent Deployment job");
targetFile.Update();
```

Geting the value back works on Farm A, but isn't working on Farm B.

I don't have access to debug on Farm B.

```
string result = (string)file.GetProperty("MyCustomProp");
```

The resulting `result` variable is empty.

I can't find any reference to object properties not beeing included on content deployment... am I missing something here?

Thanks.
PP